# Unable to make sound play in headset

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio

Top right, I click the sound icon, select sound settings, and connect my USB-headset. I can them see the headset being detected as it pops up in the menu. I click it, and expect the currently played audio to get sent to the headset instead. My problem is that it does not. The audio keeps playing through the built-in speakers.

More info:
The icon for my built-in card in the sound settings is a circuit with a note symbol on top. The symbol for the headset is just black background with a "[No](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_symbol)" symbol on it. Might mean it doesn't work somehow.

I installed pavucontrol, and notice that no second sound card shows up in there.

When connecting, the syslog says

> Jun 20 09:38:46 yuna kernel: [40144.553431] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
>
> Jun 20 09:38:46 yuna kernel: [40144.650609] input: C-Media USB Headphone Set   as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.3/input/input20
>
> Jun 20 09:38:46 yuna kernel: [40144.650895] generic-usb 0003:0D8C:000C.000B: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Device [C-Media USB Headphone Set  ] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input3
>
> Jun 20 09:38:46 yuna mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 11: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2"
> Jun 20 09:38:46 yuna mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 11 was not an MTP device

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make an external device available as audio sink and to switch to a playing stream  on plugging in we may need to add the following to our `/etc/pulse/default.pa` (for pulseaudio >= 1.0):

```
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

This needs a restart of the pulseaudio server to take effect. If daemonized to auto-spawn (this is the default) we can easily perform this with the following command:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Comment: Thanks! That's great to know, and something I've been wondering about, but it seems to be unrelated to my question? It's not that I require PA to switch automatically, it's that I can't even manually switch it over, which I assume is a prerequisite for it to work automatically.

Comment: Ok, my comment was incorrect, your suggestion _did_ solve my problem. Perhaps the answer could be re-phrased a bit anyway though, to address my first comment? :)

Comment: This worked for me too. However, after pulseaudio -k I was unable to open the sound settings from the menu bar. I then rebooted and everything started working correctly.

Comment: @MartinEden: in a default Ubuntu installation pulseaudio respawns after it was terminated. You may have disabled this. You then should be able to restart the daemon in a terminal with `pulseaudio -D`

Comment: @Takkat: This is a clean Ubuntu 16.04 install, only  a few hours old! I've changed very little

Comment: @MartinEden: in this case it may come from any other application/bug/inconvenience that made part of pulseaudio unresponsive. Don't hesitate to ask again if that error comes back.