# Volume control microsoft lifechat lx-3000

Tags: 12.04, sound, volume-control

When I plug in my MS LifeChat LX-3000 headphones into my usb drive into Dell Inspiron, I have to manually change the sound output to the headset.  The sound will sometimes automatically transfer from the speakers to the headset, and sometimes it will not.  If I leave the headphones plugged in and even have changed the output the headset, when I wake the computer from a suspend session, I do not have volume control.  Sound will still be coming from the headset, but when I change volume from my keyboard the volume remains the same. When I change the output to the speakers again, I have full control.

Is there a fix for this?  Is there a setting or a configuration file I can change?  Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I've discovered the answer to my question on another thread.  For pulseaudio >= 0, you have to add the line below to */etc/pulse/default.pa* to configure pulseaudio to change audio source on connect.

```
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

After you add this line in, make sure to restart pulseaudio with:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

The thread I found the answer on:
[Unable to make sound play in headset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153438/unable-to-make-sound-play-in-headset)

Comment: Confirmed that this works on Ubuntu 14.04 as well. Both the microphone and headphone parts of the LX-3000 are switched on connect.